# Month Class: Overzealous Refactoring? [.NET]

Tags: .net

Would creating a Month class be practical or is that a bit overzealous? I was thinking of using it to restrict integer input to 1-12 and provide helper functions for easy conversions between strings and ints and stuff. Using .NET btw

Comment: What programming language? In any programming language with reasonable Date implementations, this should not be necessary.

Comment: It's not necessarily a terrible idea. It also means that you can pass Months around instead of ints and not have to worry about them getting misinterpreted as years or days or something else represented by an int. It depends on your application.

Comment: @Matt: Using .NET. @dfan Had a few issues going around in an app and felt dirty adding `if( value < 1 || value > 12 )  {throw exception}` all over the place. That brought this thought of turning it into a class up.

Comment: @Matt, using DateTime for storing only a month often leads to subtle errors. .NET really needs a concept of date parts beyond just DateTime and TimeSpan.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the language is C#. Thought they didn't vary much though.

Comment: Sometimes it matters, but in this case there is no difference between VB and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just another level of static typing beyond what .NET natively offers. It isn't a bad thing, some languages even have it built in.

Rules for your case:

1. Make it a structure so it is as cheap as an Enum or Integer.
2. Make it immutable. That means you get a constructor but no setters.
3. Override Equals, ==, and all their friends.

Comment: Using a struct presents a problem similar to using an enum: there's nothing to stop anyone doing `var m = new Month();` which will result in `m` being invalid unless you make January the 0th month (and the default state).

Answer (score 2):

.Net actually has this built-in kind of, you just need to see the bigger picture. Not all calendars use 12 months. The information is in the `System.Globalization` namespace. If you just want the InvariantCulture info you can check out various properties and methods of:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat
```

For instance you could replace 12 with `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Length`

Honestly, 1 and 12 are pretty obvious magic numbers. But if you really want to clean things up then just right a helper method called `IsMonthNumberValid(int)` that does the 1-12 check for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), seems like they were designed for this purpose.

Comment: Enums are not restricted in range.

Comment: Enums are restricted in range.

Comment: They aren't. That's why I skipped the enums. I'm avoiding getting 0's in fields that are supposed to be for months. Turns out you can do `(Month)0` (presuming Month is an enum that starts with 1) and no exception gets thrown.

Comment: Enums are little more than just a list of constants. If you write  `Month x = (Month) -427` you will not not get a runtime or compiler error.

Comment: are you talking about assignments bases on the underlying type? If so yes they aren't.

Comment: So wait, your whole design is to make helper functions easier for other developers in your team and you're concerned with them passing in invalid month values for a ENUM named MONTHS, whilst working under your OWN code base? Seems like Analysis paralysis to me.

Comment: The value comes from a user control, which doesn't know that it's supposed to be returning an enum. Since there are no restrictions to enums, 0's still get passed around. Happens in various places. And yes. This has been bothering me every time I've encountered something like this and I'd spend a bit of time wondering whether I should or shouldn't so I finally decided to ask it here. XD

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine any circumstances where this would be a good idea.

The time you spend writing "helper functions for easy conversions between strings and ints and stuff" could be spent adding real value to your application.

Comment: For a huge system wouldn't this add value in the long run?